# Trying to run a script, using Exchange Online, connection works, Get-UnifiedGroup works, but Set doesn't exist?

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

So I'm trying to run a script that hides certain email addresses from a client's outlook addressbook.

```
$Username = "xxx"
$Password = "xxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.SharePointSiteUrl} | select PrimarySmtpAddress, SharePointSiteUrl | Set-UnifiedGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true 
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

This will hide all the email addresses that have a sharepoint URL connected to them from creating team sites. Anyway, Get-UnifiedGroup works, but when I do the following:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

it says this:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup: The term 'Set-UnifiedGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've searched google but can't seem to find a proper solution to my problem... I also did the following commands, to no avail:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

and

```
Install-Module MSOnline
```

I don't know where to look anymore, I'm by not means used to writing Powershell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Microsoft documentation "Set-UnifiedGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled" does not take pipeline input.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps)

I would suggest trying:

```
$Username = "xxx"
$Password = "xxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
$groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.SharePointSiteUrl} | select PrimarySmtpAddress, SharePointSiteUrl

foreach ($group in $groups){
    set-unifiedgroup -identity $group.PrimarySmtpAddress -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
}

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

With regards to "Set-UnifiedGroup: The term 'Set-UnifiedGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

You will need to add the appropriate role in the exchange admin centre to be able to access the cmdlet.

You will need to be an administrator to make these changes;

https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/?rfr=Admin_o365

Login and select "Permissions" on the left.

I think "Organization Management" should give you the cmdlet you are looking for.

Edit that role and add the user that you are using for the above powershell script to the members list.

This will usually take 30-60 minutes to become effective.

Comment: Yes... It seems like I needed an account with more privileges, I contact my client and asked for a higher account and now it worked. Thanks! Did not know this...